# WordPress Multisite — Have same navigation, sidebar and footer across all sites.

Tags: multisite

I've been looking around for a while now and still can't find a solution so am asking here. I have a site where anyone can sign up and create their own blog as a subdirectory of the main website.

What I want is for every blog to have the same navigation (in essence the same header), footer and sidebar as the main website of the network. I couldn't find what I was looking for in the WordPress Codex. Has anyone found a solution to this before or can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this functionality, You will need to install same Theme across all network website and enable it by default for them.

Comment: This would not provide the same navigation unless the menu items are hard coded into the theme. Widgets (sidebar & footer) would also have to be arranged on each site to match. Maybe expand your answer to include this information.